# Converting English to Set Theory Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am having trouble finding expressions for the following. My attempts are separated from the question with a semicolon.

---

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be events. Find expressions for:

- only $A$ occurs; $A \cap \neg B \cap \neg C$
- only $A$ doesn't occur; $\neg A \cap B \cap C $
- $A$ and $B$ don't occur, but $C$ does; $\neg A \cap \neg B \cap C$
- $A$ and $B$ occur, but $C$ doesn't occur; $A \cap B \cap \neg C$
- at least one of $A$ and $B$, but not $C$ occurs; $(A \cup B) \cap \neg C $
- at least one of the events occur; $A \cup B \cup C$
- at least two of the events occur; $(A \cup B) \cup (B \cup C) \cup (C \cup A)$
- all three events occur; $A \cap B \cap C$
- none of the events occur; $\neg A \cap \neg B \cap \neg C$
- at most one of the events occurs; $(A - (A \cap B \cap C)) \cup (B - (A \cap B \cap C)) \cup (C - (A\cap B\cap C))$  .

---

Could someone please let me know if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, except for the last one. But from the others it appears that you know what you're doing, so I bet you can figure it out for the last one as well. (Also, as a small note: using $\neg A$ for the complement of $A$ is somewhat non-standard. Perhaps you'd prefer using $A^c$ instead. Of course that is up to you, as long as the person who's going to be reading this understands.)

Comment: Your answer for "at least two of the events occur" is wrong.  Look at upir correct e "all three occur" answer for a hint at your mistake here.

Comment: Should "at least two events occur" be $(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (C \cap A)$?

Comment: At most one event occurs should be $(A \cap B^{c} \cap C^{c}) \cup (A^{c} \cap B \cap C^{c}) \cup (A^{c} \cap B^{c} \cap C)$ ?

Comment: @stackofhay42 yes, the commented answers for "at least two events occur" and "at most one event occur" are correct. If you want to use the minus operation then it would be $(A-(B\cup C))\cup (B-(A\cup C))\cup (C-(A\cup B)))$

Comment: Thanks if u make post I'll give right answer